Launch PuTTY from Linux cli with serial parameters
I can launch a serial session from the Linux command line with:
putty -serial /dev/ttyS0

But I can't find an option to set the serial speed.  Google AI tells me that this should work:
putty -serial /dev/ttyS0 -speed 115200

But it reports that -speed is an unrecognized option.  Maybe that works for Windows users.  Can I do this in Linux?

Use the -sercfg parameter (the -speed is hallucinated):
putty -serial /dev/ttyS0 -sercfg 115200


Great, that does it!  I hate that I didn't see that in the man page.

@Mike An alternative would be to create a session with all the parameters set within the putty gui and call it as putty -load <session>.
